# Geometrical Brownian Motion Simulation in R

Tags: r, simulation

I used two different methods to simulate the GBM. one with the SDE and one with the analytical solution for f(t). But I get different result. I have already set my random seed. I can't figure out what the difference is. Thanks a lot!

```
set.seed(12345)
f0 <-102
mu <-(0.05)
sigma <-0.08
T <-0.5
t <- seq(1/365,T,by=1/365)
n <-length(t)
#method 1
f<-numeric(n)
f<-sapply(t,function(t) f0*exp((mu-0.5*sigma^2)*t+sigma*rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=sqrt(t))))
diff <- f- f0
plot(t,f,type="l")

#method 2
dt <- 1/365
f2<-numeric(n)
f2[1]<- f0
delta<-0
for (i in 2:n) {
  delta = mu*f2[i-1]*dt+sigma*f2[i-1]*rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=sqrt(dt))
  f2[i]=f2[i-1]+delta
}
plot(t,f2,type="l")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qAyb.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

The reason why are different is that the first method is just wrong. Basically the process you are simulating is not a continuous process as at every time step you are generating a new random variable while you should generate just the increment and sum to the old value.

This modification to the first method will fix the problem:

```
#method 1
f<-numeric(n)
f<-f0*exp(cumsum((mu-sigma*sigma/2)*T/n + sigma*sqrt(T/n)*rnorm(n)))
diff <- f- f0
plot(t,f,type="l")
```

Comment: Could we know what the proposed analytical approach (method 1) is called and where it comes from?

Comment: There is not a name, just for each time step i, there is a new random variable X_i.